# running elasticsearch queries on linux

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

What 's the correct way of running elasticsearch queries on linux? I came up with the code below but it seems that it is not correct because of many errors that I see.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/INDEXED_REPOSITORY/_search?q="constant_score" : {"filter" : { "terms" : { "description" : ["heart", "cancer", and  more than 10000 keywords ]}}}}
```

Comment: Add single quotes around the entire URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few things, do it like this:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/INDEXED_REPOSITORY/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter" : { 
        "terms" : { 
          "description" : ["heart", "cancer", and  more than 10000 keywords ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

or on a single line:

curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/INDEXED_REPOSITORY/_search -d '{"query": {"constant_score": {"filter" : {"terms" : {"description" : ["heart", "cancer", and  more than 10000 keywords ]}}}}}'
```

Comment: Thanks @Val but I am still getting the following error:   -bash: query:: command not found
[x@sbbioddlp002 ~]$     "constant_score": {
-bash: constant_score:: command not found
[x@sbbioddlp002 ~]$       "filter" : {
-bash: filter: command not found
[x@sbbioddlp002 ~]$         "terms" : {
-bash: terms: command not found
[x@sbbioddlp002 ~]$           "description" : ["heart", "cancer"]
-bash: description: command not found
[x@sbbioddlp002 ~]$         }
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Comment: It looks like you have bad new lines in your query, see my update and try the one-liner command.